# What are these grey scoop-shaped parts with a hole for an axle?

Tags: part-identification

I got these in a lot that I bought and I have no idea how to identify them. They have dates from 05 and 02, but no part numbers.

[image: unidentified LEGO parts]

Comment: Pretty sure they are dinosaur pieces. Should be under animal parts on bricklink

Answer (score 3):

This is:

[Part# 42042 : Light Gray Bionicle Krana Holder 3 x 4](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=42042#T=C)

Keyword: 3 x 4, Color: Light Gray

it appears in [13 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=42042&colorID=9&in=A)

Comment: Hi @Yankees27 - welcome to Bricks! If this has answered your question, it would be great if you could click on the tick to the left - this lets people know that your question has been answered, and gives both you and Syberion some reputation ;)